# Ribbon Display Rules - ValueRule - LookUp Value

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon

I have added a button to my ribbon and I want to define a DisplayRule/ValueRule
that checks if a lookup field has a certain value. 
I don't want to use the GUID but the actual name of the value because
GUIDS might differ on Development, Test and Production.

```
<DisplayRule Id="MyCompany.Form.account.MainTab.Actions.ShowWebSite.Command.DisplayRule.ValueRule">
  <ValueRule Default="true" InvertResult="false" Field="new_countryid" Value="France" />
</DisplayRule>
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Would *disabling* the button be just as good as *hiding* it?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, you can't setup a javascript rule on the display.  You might be forced to set it up on the enable...

You can create a custom javascript rule that runs javascript that looks up the name of the lookup field.  Something like this:

```
var name = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_myLookupAttribute").getSelectedOption().text;
return name == "Foo";
```

Comment: A custom javascript rule works on Enable Rules but is there a way to use this on Display Rules?

Comment: @RobHufschmitt (and anyone coming after): No, CustomRules only work on Enable, not Display.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the attribute which will contain the GUID.  So try putting the GUID of France or using "new_countryid_name" for the field.

Comment: Using the guid is not an option as I mentioned in my description and using new_countryid_name is not an existing property.